# Propagate Scroll Event from Iframe to parent in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, scroll

I have an iframe inside a wordpress page. The size of the iframe is set automatically to its content size, so it is necessary to scroll vertically to see the content.
It works ok on all browsers, but Firefox "steals" the scroll event when the iframe is hovered so the parent page can´t be scrolled down.
How could I propagate the scroll event to the parent?

Comment: I have exactly same problem !!! Any help >?

Comment: Me too. Curious to see if there is any solution (I actually have a weird behaviour on Safari as well; it propagates/bubbles the *scrollUp* but not the *scrollDown* :/ )